# Free anti-theft software for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, security

I'm looking for some anti-theft software similar to LoJack, but free. I would like the software to meet these requirements,

- Gratis
- Compatiable with Windows 10
- Provides GeoLocation on device
- Provides picture of person using device
- Provides screenshot or live view of the screen
- Low memory footprint
- Only starts recording information when theft is reported (on the website where this data would be found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm currently using Prey which seems to be the best free software that I've seen. It provides free protection for 3 devices and meets the requirements found within the question. It's available for many devices including desktops, laptops, tablets, and phones.

## [Prey](https://preyproject.com/) (open source)

> Prey is a lightweight application that will help you track and find your laptop or mobile if it ever gets stolen. It works in Windows, Mac OsX, Linux and Android.
>
> [image]

Comment: I'm using it too. A minor disadvantage is that blocking sometimes delayed up until 30 minutes, so this will add to the time between your device being stolen and it signalling "I'm stolen". Not a big issue, and it may have improved since my last tests.